# How to transfer strings into integers with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nameerror

I'm trying to transfer strings into integers from the `plans_data`:

```
 import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
plans_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Country', 'Currency', 'Mobile', 'Basic', 'Standard', 'Premium'])
for index, row in countries_list.iterrows():
    country = row['ID']  
    url = f'https://help.netflix.com/en/node/24926/{country}'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find("table", class_="c-table")
    try:
        plan_country = pd.read_html(results.prettify())[0] #creates a list(!) of dataframe objects
        plan_country = plan_country.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 0':'Currency'})
        plan_country = pd.DataFrame(plan_country.iloc[0,:]).transpose()
        plans_data = pd.concat([plans_data, plan_country], ignore_index=True)
    except AttributeError:
        country_name = row['Name']
        print(f'No data found for {country_name}.')
    plans_data.loc[index, 'Country'] = row['Name']
plans_data
```

Firstly, I atempted to transfer using function `float`:

```
 # 1. Here we import pandas
 import pandas as pd
 # 2. Here we import numpy
 import numpy as np
 ans_2_1_ = float(plans_data['Basic', 'Standard', 'Premium'])
```

However, I always get the NameError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15368/3072127414.py in <module>
      3 # 2. Here we import numpy
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 ans_2_1_ = float(plans_data['Basic', 'Standard', 'Premium'])

NameError: name 'plans_data' is not defined
```

How can I solve this problem?

If my code is not appropriate for my task "transfer strings into integers", can you advise me on how to convert?

Comment: How is the second code snippet related to the first? Are they in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the second piece of code does not know what `plans_data` is, so first make sure they `plans_data` is defined where you do that, ie in the same file or the same Jupyter notebook

second problem is that `plans_data['Basic', 'Standard', 'Premium']` is not valid syntax

Thirdly, and probably is your real question, how to convert the values in those columns to floats.

Elements in columns 'Basic', 'Standard', 'Premium' are strings in currency format eg `'£ 5.99'`. You can convert them to floats as such (you need to do it for each column):

```
ans_2_1_ = plans_data['Basic'].str[1:].astype(float)
... # same for Standard and Premium
```